# How to keep the ng-model binding of a jQuery clone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, binding, drag-and-drop

I'm currently trying to get a drag and drop working with the help of clones.

I've got a list on the left and want to drag it to the right, but keep the element on the left aswell. Therefor I create a clone on the left and drag the original element. The problem I got now is, that the binding of the clone and the ng-model element is lost. Is there any way to prevent this from happening or re-establishing the binding?

Here is a jsfiddle to show what I'm talking about (simulating the drag&drop by clicking on one of the elements): https://jsfiddle.net/dokuzcan/6jmwt9hv/1/

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("CloneController", function ($scope, $log) {

//will change on btn click
$scope.value = "";

//Error messsage during copy / append
$scope.error = "";

$scope.list = [];
//build ng-repeat list
$scope.initList = function () {
    //fillup the list

    $scope.list.push({
        id: 1,
        value: "This is Angular"
    });
    $scope.list.push({
        id: 2,
        value: "This is Angular"
    }); 
}

//refreshing list:
// list items will be removed
// and will readd. additional all cloned element will be
// removed from the DOM - Object
$scope.refresh = function (){

    //reseting list
    $scope.list = [];

    //re-rendering ng-repeat list 

    //removing cloned elements from note
    $(".clone").remove();

    $scope.initList();
}

//copy element by jquery and append 
//this to his parent element
$scope.jQueryClone = function () {
    try {
        //elment to clone
        var toClone = $("#cloneElement");
        //cloning element with angular
        var clonedEl = toClone.clone(true, true);
        //adding element to the container
        $("#container").append(clonedEl);

        //adding class
        clonedEl.addClass("clone");

        clonedEl.id = "blub";
    } catch (e) {
        error = e.message;
    }
}

//change value to see, that the copied element
//has no angular binding anymore
$scope.changeValue = function () {
    $scope.list[0].value += " Changed ";
}

// see: directive:move
$scope.move = function (evt, element) {
    $log.debug(" moving the element ", evt, element);
    // $("#movedContainer").append(element);
}
});

myApp.directive("move", ["$log", function ($log) {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {

        //on click the element will be append to an other element
        elem.bind("click", function () {
            $log.debug(" element.bind.blick ", elem);
            $("#movedContainer").append(elem);
        });
    }
}
}]);
```

Comment: Silly (?) question: Why are you dragging the original element instead of the clone?